# Python creating a list that matches with random generated list

Tags: python, list, random

I'm trying to create a program where a user inputs numbers between 1 and 9 and the numbers are stored in a list and the program generates 4 numbers between 1 and 10 and then a it states which numbers match.
[image]

Can anyone help me with my code?

```
import random
def main():
   print("You are asked to pick 4 unique numbers in the range of 1 to 10.")
       number,list = user_input()
      randomlist = random_gen()

def user_input():
    for i in range(4):
        while True:
          number = float(input("Enter a number: ")
             if number < 1 : or number > 10
                print("Must be in the range of 1 to 10")
                else:
                     break
        list. Append(number)

def random_gen():
    randomlist = random.sample(range(1,10),5)

    for a in list:
        for b in randomlist:
            if(a==b):
                 match=match=1
                break

print("\n\nNumbers picked:",list)
print("Balls Drawn:",randomlist)
print("Number of matches:",match)
```

Comment: One issue I see immediately is your functions don't appear to return anything..

Comment: Is it important to consider ordering of numbers?

Comment: Your code has a lot of errors, and too many indentation errors. Python is very sensitive to indentations

Answer (score 0):

**Get input from user**

```
 user_input = list(map(int, input("Enter input: ").split()))
```

`Enter input: 3 4 9 6`

**Generate 4 random number**

```
 balls_drawn = random.sample(list(range(1, 10)), 4)
```

`balls_drawn = [8, 7, 4, 6]`
`user_input [3, 4, 9, 6]`

**Count the matches**

```
sum([1 for v in user_input if v in balls_drawn])
```

output `2`